# Regex to lookahead User name: and match the word behind until the end of line

Tags: regex

I am trying to write Regex to lookahead User name: and match the word behind until the end of line:

The regex is:

```
^(?=User name:)\s*\[A-Za-z]+
```

and the text is:

```
Action:         NEW

User name:      Matthew Thomas
Job title:      Dealer Account Manager
Direct report:      Craig Carlson
Department:         Dealer Account Management
Location:       Milton, QLD
Employment type:    Permanent Full Time
Start date:         15/07/2013
Finish date:


__________________________________________
Decision Point 3
--------------
Read Only
```

---

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> `^(?=User name:)\s*\[A-Za-z]+`

- `(?=User name:)` what you need is lookbehind, not lookahead:
  `(?<=User name:)`
- `^(?=User name:)` - lookbehind will search at the beginning, regardless where you place it in your expression, so it's looking for "User name:" followed by beginning of line and some spaces. Include beginning of line too:
  `(?<=^User name:)`
- put your name in brackets, so it'll be easier it capture it:
  `([A-Za-z]+)`
- `[A-Za-z]` there can be also spaces in your name, or even some letters with accent, I would modify it like this:
  `(\S.+)`
  (a none space character (following white spaces) followed by everything until end of line)

The whole expression is: 
`(?<=^User name:)\s*(\S.+)$`

You can test is [here](https://regex101.com/r/k2Vdrq/1).

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want.

I put your sample text into text.txt file.

If you simply want to grep the line, there is the solution:

```
grep -E "^User name:\s*[A-Za-z ]+$" text.txt
User name:      Matthew Thomas
```

If you want only the name, we can enhance the command with sed:

```
grep -E "^User name:\s*[A-Za-z ]+$" text.txt | sed -e '1,$s/^User name:\s*\([A-Za-z ]*\)$/\1/'
```